Implementing IIR and FIR filter using vectorization and SIMD
I am learning  fir and iir(biquad) filter implementation for audio applications using C on ARM. Its recommended to use vectorization of input data and SIMD operations for optimization . But i am unable to find any C code implementations online or any resource which is easy to understand and beginner friendly . please tell where to find such code or resource?

Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. I am definitely not an expert on the matter, but I really think that blending filter implementation in C and vectorised operations (SIMD) in embedded environments is not “beginner" at all, so I am not sure you’ll find any “beginner-friendly” resources on the topic. Unless, of course, we don’t assign the same meaning to the word beginner. Don’t get me wrong; I do believe this is an extremely interesting and nice topic, but I believe you should divide the problem into (at least two) smaller pieces: C implementation and vectorisation, that is.
